# Can't execute script from udev rule

Tags: scripts, udev, 17.10

I'm trying to create an udev rules on Ubuntu 17.10. After hours of testing I desperately ended up with the following rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/98-intelpwm.rules`:

(it's for testing purpose only!)

```
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/home/user/intel_gpu/test.sh"
```

The script itself:

```
$ ll /home/user/intel_gpu/test.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 56 Oct 22 01:38 /home/user/intel_gpu/test.sh*
```

---

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/echo 1 >> /home/user/intel_gpu/test.output
```

When I run `udevadm test /module/usb_storage` I can see the rule fires but the `test.output` is not created (or if I create it manually, it's not updated).

```
calling: test
version 234
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          234
file size:         9138024 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1910832 bytes
nodes              7227112 bytes
Load module index
Failed to read $container of PID 1, ignoring: Permission denied
Found container virtualization none.
timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/lib/systemd/network' changed
Parsed configuration file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Created link configuration context.
timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/39-usbmuxd.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb-media-players.rules
...
Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/98-intelpwm.rules
Reading rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
rules contain 393216 bytes tokens (32768 * 12 bytes), 35397 bytes strings
27571 strings (233697 bytes), 24356 de-duplicated (201516 bytes), 3216 trie nodes used
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.'
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.'
RUN '/home/user/intel_gpu/test.sh' /etc/udev/rules.d/98-intelpwm.rules:1
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/module/usb_storage
SUBSYSTEM=module
USEC_INITIALIZED=4988363806
run: '/home/user/intel_gpu/test.sh'
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you check the permissions of the folder and the output file `ls -lR /home/user/intel_gpu`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't actually. Erased the system months ago.

Answer (score 0):

To apply the `udev` rule, you have to use `udevadm trigger`. Additionally you can tell `udevadm trigger` which action event to trigger.

If you just run `udevadm trigger` all devices are triggered and there will be some `add` actions which will trigger your script because it is valid for all devices.
If you would like to run the `udev` rule for a specific device that is already available, you might have to add the `-c, --action=ACTION` option.

```
udevadm trigger --action=add /sys/<path-to-your-device>
```

I woudl strongly recommend to limit the matches of your `udev` rule because at the moment it does match for any device and you script will run multiple times.

Comment: The thing is that the script is not triggered at all (or is triggered and fails with an error - how to figure that out?). I tried to insert usb stick, `test.output` file is not updated.

I understand it's a super global rule, for now I just want to prove that it works.

Comment: I also tried `udevadmin trigger...` as suggested, can see the event in `udevadm monitor`, but the `test.output` file is not updated.